# Forward email from exim to another mail server on different port

Tags: ubuntu, exim

Exim seems to be very flexible and configurable. What would be the best approach for me to forward an incoming email to exim to another mail server running on a different port like lamson? I am running exim and lamson on the same ubuntu machine.

Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `manualroute` router to point to the appropriate transport, where you override the standard port. Something like (untested):

```
begin routers

lamson_host_relay:
    driver = manualroute
    route_list = * lamson.server.com byname
    transport = lamson_smtp

begin transports

lamson_smtp:
    driver = smtp
    port = 666
```

Comment: it does not work. But maybe it's lamson

Comment: What do exim logs say?

Comment: temporarily rejected RCPT ... remote host address is the local host

Comment: Aaah. It's because lamson and exim is on the same server =(